# How to check if array inside object is empty JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, loops, object

```
const isEmpty = Object.keys(data).every((key) => {
  return data[key].length === 0;
});
```

How can I check if all arrays in objects are empty.
Problem with this code I tried is that I get this:

```
data {
    0: Array[]
    1: Array[]
    2: Array[]
}
data {
    0: Array[]
    1: Array[1]
    2: Array[]
}
```

For first object I get false and that's okay but for the second I get true but I want to get false until all of arrays.length > 0, so I need to get true only for this situation:

```
obj {
    0: Array[1]
    1: Array[1]
    2: Array[1]
}
```

Comment: If you know that you want the following `arrays.length > 0`. Then why don't you use it instead of `length === 0`?

Comment: your `data` is completely invalid. What should `Array[0]` be? If that is really your code, that will not return false or true but just throw errors ...

Comment: What do you mean by writing `Array[0]` etc.? if you mean an array with 0 elements then your solution will give `true` for the first and `false` for the second, not `false` for the first and `true` for the second. Also, your desired result is unclear, you say you want it to be true until all of `arrays.length > 0`, but then say "_I need to get true **only** for this situation_", which suggests you want `true` only when all `arrays.length`'s equal 1

Comment: I created the solution

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could check the lenght of all values.

```js
const isEmpty = data => !Object.values(data).every(({ length }) => length);

console.log(isEmpty({ 0: [], 1: [], 2: [] }));
console.log(isEmpty({ 0: [], 1: [1], 2: [] }));
console.log(isEmpty({ 0: [0], 1: [1], 2: [2] }));
```

Comment: I think `const isEmpty = data => Object.values(data).every(({ length }) => !length);` otherwise the function should be named `someEmpty` or something like that.

Comment: naming is up to op. i would prefer `hasEmptyArrays` ...

Comment: Ah, you're right. I missed the fact that the desired behaviour doesn't match the name OP has given the function.

Answer (score 1):

Use Object.values method.

```
Object.values(data).some(it => !it.length)
```

Comment: This will not work but you are close enough

Comment: @Rajesh sorry i forgot `!` operator before `it.length`

Answer (score 0):

The solution

```
function CheckArray(obj) {
  this.haveItems = false;

  this.onCheck = function (obj) {
    let createdArr = Object.values(obj);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < createdArr.length; i++) {
      if (createdArr[i].length > 0) {
        this.haveItems = true;
        break;
      }
    }
  };
}

let data = {
  0: [],
  1: [],
  2: [],
};

let a = new CheckArray();
a.onCheck(data);

console.log(a);
```